# How to redirect to SSL and www except for subdomains

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have example.com and I want all requests to arrive at: https://www.example.com

I also have subdomain.example.com and I want all these requests to arrive at https://subdomain.example.com

Answer (score 0):

Need more input. You use apache ?

then something like :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*) https://subdomain.example.com/$1 [R,L] 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:*>
    ServerName example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L] 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Yes, I have DirectAdmin if that helps further. I will take a look at this, currently I've been using some htaccess rules. Thank you. I'll update llater.